# Como fazer live stream basico com HTML5 vídeo API e PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Gostaria de saber o básico sobre como criar(fazer) um sistema de live stream...tenho um script de blog em php aonde criei um sistema de usuários e até mesmo um sistema de amizades porém gostaria de adicionar a possibilidade de cada usuário criar uma "espécie" de canal próprio para fazer live stream de conteúdos (games, reviews, tutos, etc...) transmitindo para os amigos em suas listas ou publicamente. Já observei inúmeros scripts internet afora porém eles possuem muito mais do que preciso não busco nada com filtros ou sistemas próprios, eu gostaria de criar para implementar em meu script já pronto.

Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda. Desde exemplos simples até dicas de estudo grato a todos bom fim de ano :)

Comment: Você está usando o protocolo RTMP?

Comment: Não estou usando nada. Estou a procura de material de estudo (indicações, etc...).

Comment: https://github.com/qwantix/php-rtmp-client

Comment: Pesquise por "webrtc", é uma API de navegadores acessível por javascript e feita exatamente para o que tipo de problema que você tem, transmissão de vídeo/audio/dados em tempo real entre navegadores. Veja [este demo](https://simplewebrtc.com/demo.html) que mostra criação de canal com live stream de webcams, o mesmo pode ser feito para compartilhamento de telas (embora o suporte ainda seja meio restrito).

Comment: @BrunoRB sim, estou a algum tempo a usar WebRTC em testes e mostrou-se a melhor opcao dentro de minhas necessidades

Answer (score 8):

### Live-stream (transmissão ao vivo)

- Conforme esta reposta no [SO-en](https://stackoverflow.com/a/224182/1518921), o PHP *não é indicado* para o uso de "live-stream" (transmissão ao vivo).

  Não vou dizer que é impossível fazer PHP, mas talvez seja um duro caminho, pois será necessário que algo capture a WebCam da pessoa que transmite o video, salve em um documento os dados e as pessoas que assistem ficam esperando novos `bytes` serem adicionados ao servidor, isto **pode ser muito custoso** para *desenvolver* e para o *servidor*.

  Veja um exemplo é o Youtube, eles fazem transmissões ao-vivo e exibição de videos que estão no servidor, enquanto o site `youtube.com` está em um servidor otimizado para páginas Web, os vídeos estão em outro servidor totalmente isolado, que é otimizado para transmissão de vídeos e é provável que o "live-stream" deles esteja em outro servidor ainda (ou seja 3 servidores com tecnologias diferentes). Portanto a transmissão dos dados não são feitos por uma linguagem como "PHP", mas provavelmente por uma tecnologia específica para transmissões.

  Você pode até conseguir usar PHP para isto, mas provavelmente o seu servidor não irá aguentar um dia.
- E conforme está resposta no [SO-en](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189709/1518921)
  para gravar o vídeo com HTML5, será necessário usar [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/). Isto habilita transmissão de áudio e vídeo.

### Alternativa RTMP (Requer Flash)

Eu não testei ainda, mas o caminho é este:

- [PHP cliente](https://github.com/qwantix/php-rtmp-client)
- [Gravar Webcam com Jquery (requer Flash)](https://github.com/tnktp/jquery-flash-webcam)
- [modulo RTMP para Nginx](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module)

> Assim como o Youtube, você pode separar em dois servidores um você pode usar o Apache para página Web e o "cliente PHP" (usando porta 80) e no Ngnix você irá só usar para o RTMP (*eu acho* que o padrão é porta 1935)

### Alternativa não live-stream

Porém existe o seguinte script para gravar com PHP (se não for em tempo real) que você pode usar [PHP Webcam Video Recorder](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpwebcamvideorecorder/)

Comment: Pois é agradeço a resposta parece ser bem detalhada porém isso é "vídeo-stream" de um arquivo já hospedado no servidor (já até cheguei a testar este método) porém busco "live-stream"

Comment: @LauroMoraes *eu sei* que não é video-stream o que você precisa, eu escrevi entre parênteses (se não for em tempo real), é como está escrito na resposta, para o html5 gravar é necessário "WebRTC" e PHP não é a tecnologia recomendável para gerenciar a transmissão. Portanto não tem como lhe proporcionar uma solução ou tutorial de algo que não aparentemente *não existe* :) espero que não leve a mal o meu comentário

Answer (score 2):

SIM, é possível realizar esta proposta com PHP.

Na verdade o Youtube (tanto YouT quanto outras plataformas similares) roda graças ao **FFmpeg**. E isto não quer dizer que é um servidor diferente dos outros que você utiliza para programar (a não ser pela escalabilidade e velocidade, memória etc)

Então se você está usando o Linux, estude este poderoso aplicativo (linhas de comando e formas de uso) muito importante, Tanto é que php possui uma bilioteca nativa que trabalha com FFmpeg.

No caso do PHP pensa asim, vamos falar do seu projeto (ou ideia): o PHP vai rodar no servidor, então você vai usar para converter os arquivos, organizar, (ler a stream etc) e disponibilizar para o usuário.

Mas para gravar, você não consegue com PHP nem com Javascript, porque eles não estão conectados com os dispositivos do computador (como a câmera por exemplo). Então para o usuário enviar um vídeo você precisa de outra questão.

Por isso todos indicaram o uso do Flash, que até então era o único dispositivo que conectava na câmera e Microfone (não esquece isso). Mas agora tem o Html5 que também pode se conectar nestes dispotivos. Então você já pode enviar um vídeo dos seus usuários - com Flash ou com Html5.

Vai dar trabalho, mas vale a pena a pesquisa nessa área.

Eu já fiz algo parecido, mas apenas um usuário enviado vídeo para um servidor PHP e vários usuário conectando ao vivo e assistindo. Com um aplicativo da Adobe chamado Adobe Media Live Encoder. Tinha uma versão que era gratuito, hoje em dia é pago. :/

No teu caso é uma Programação mais ousada, mas vale a pena.

Links: 
https://ffmpeg.org/

-- não posso publicar mais links porque é minha primeira participação no Stack ;)

Comment: Bom neste molde nao seria "live-stream" mas somente "stream".