# Ligação de voz entre dois pontos

Tags: php, javascript, html, html5

Gostaria de estudar sobre, ler como é feito e todos detalhes possíveis sobre realizar ligações de voz entra dois pontos A e B

Igual funciona essas ligações entre usuários como o viber, WhatsApp, facebook fornecem.

É possível usando PHP HTML5 JavaScript ?

Answer (score 5):

### Sobre o PHP:

Não vou dizer que é impossível fazer PHP, mas talvez seja um duro caminho, pois será necessário que algo capture o áudio das pessoas na conferencia, salve em documentos estes dados e as pessoas que houvem a conferencia ficam esperando novos bytes serem adicionados ao servidor, isto pode ser muito custoso **para desenvolver** e **para o servidor**.

- Relatado: [Como fazer live stream basico com HTML5 vídeo API e PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/45344/3635)

### Sobre o HTML5 ou JavaScript API:

Nativamente não é possível fazer streaming de comunicação, será necessário um plugin especifico.

> Nota: O *Google Chrome Canary* (para desenvolvedores) já suporta isto

Conforme está resposta do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6992944/1518921) algumas tecnologias estão sendo desenvolvidas, porém não foram implementadas e provavelmente irão demorar de implementar devido as dificuldades, já que são coisas consideradas muito "novas" (me refiro ao HTML/JavaScript integrar tantas funcionalidades "diversificadas" que antes nem se imaginava em ser algo "nativo"):

- [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/blog/introducingwebrtc-anopenreal-timecommunicationsproject) (Pode ser instalado na maioria dos browsers modernos)
- [Device API](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/NOTE-dap-api-reqs-20091015/)
- [media capture](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html-media-capture-20110414/)
- [API](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-media-capture-api-20100928/)

http://www.adobe.com/products/adobe-media-server-family.html

Comment: "[PHP] não é uma tecnologia recomendada para transmissão de dados do gênero (Streaming)" - por que? Se você não cita o(s) motivo(s) fica parecendo que é só sua opinião.

Comment: @AndréRibeiro Obrigado pelo comentário, eu entendi. Editei a resposta, me diga se é aceitável agora. Obrigado mais uma vez.

Comment: Boa resposta! Mas usaríamos PHP para transmitir tipo com websockets

Comment: @GabrielHenrique Seria bem custoso ao servidor fazer tal processo, a não ser que você queira transmitir os "endereços apenas". Você pode até conseguir usar PHP para isto, mas provavelmente o seu servidor não irá aguentar um dia.

Comment: Ao dar um voto negativo por favor justifique, não irei ficar chateado, só gostaria de saber aonde posso melhorar.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Muito bom. +1 para para reparar o negativo sem motivo que te deram.

Answer (score 1):

Qualquer linguagem que suporte socket pode ser utilizada para transmitir voz, umas possuem maior facilidade outras nem tanto.

De modo geral as aplicações citadas por você possuem um servidor central que funciona como ponto de retransmissão para os clientes, "pra que isso é necessário ?"

Segurança - Os clientes não precisam ter uma porta aberta no PC de cara para a internet, imagina você ter que fazer redirecionamento de portas e configuração de nat se estiver atras de um roteador.

Controle - E se uma destas empresas precisar legalmente Espionar/escutar/grampear um usuário ? isso só será possível caso exista um nível de controle, nestes casos as transmissões precisam passar pelo servidor central, outro tipo de controle seria recodificar o audio em codecs para consumir a menor banda possível, não enviar transmissão durante a ligação no caso de silencio em um dos lados para mais uma vez poupar banda, etc.

A arquitetura é simples:

Cliente(A) <------> SERVIDOR <------> Cliente(B)

O Servidor sim precisam ter uma ou várias portas abertas de cara para a internet (de modo geral portas UDP) para que os clientes consigam se conectar, então indiscutivelmente neste servidor central você vai precisar desenvolver em alguma linguagem (java, php, perl, python, C, etc), o core central precisa ficar em listem nas portas definidas por você, deve ser capaz de suportar várias conexões simultâneas na mesma porta de forma concorrente/threads ou seja ele deve ser capaz de executar várias tarefas simultaneamente (ligações de vários clientes acontecendo ao mesmo tempo). O Servidor é o responsável por receber os frames de voz no lado do clienteA e reenviar para o ClienteB

Os clientes devem ser capaz de fechar comunicação socket com o servidor (conectar ao servidor) e transmitir os blocos de voz capturados pelo microfone em um buffer de tamanho fixo (2048, 4096, etc), deste modo os dados saem via socket do clienteA para o servidor central que reenvia esta transmissão para o clienteB.

Esta é a ideia básica por traz de qualquer ligação de voz feita sob IP, claro existem maneiras de requintar e melhorar o processo como tentar tirar do servidor central um pouco de carga e deixar a codificação/decodificação do áudio para ser feita no cliente.

Você deve ter notado que trabalhando com socket o seu servidor não precisa ser escrito na mesma linguagem que os clients.

Você pode sair do conceito e tentar escrever o básico sem ter um servidor central, para inciar faça uma comunicação ponto a ponto em uma rede interna e porque não via internet, tudo que vai precisar para estes passos é fazer que ambos os IPs se conectem diretamente por socket, começe enviando texto igual um chat, seu próximo passo será enviar áudio através do buffer, ao invés de texto você pode querer experimentar enviar um array em float point para ser codificado e tocado durante o recebimento dos frames pelo socket no clienteB.